# Add "www." to URL string

Tags: java, android

I need to check a URL string, and if the URL does not contain "www.", insert it in the correct position.

For example, the strings on the left should be transformed as indicated:

```
www.myweb.com        => www.myweb.com
myweb.com            => www.myweb.com
http://myweb.com     => http://www.myweb.com or www.myweb.com
http://www.myweb.com => http://www.myweb.com or www.myweb.com
```

Comment: For what you need that? Just curious.

Comment: used for opening a url on a webview and some urls are not supported without www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as:

```
 if(!str.contains("www")){
  if(str.contains("://"))
    str=str.replace("://","://www.");
  else
    str="www."+str;
}
```

Comment: I think this should work. But you could simplify your code if you would do `if(!str.contains("www")) str = str.replace("://","://www");`

Comment: is that fine now, i delete my answer and edit your's, If my answer is wrong then rollback change

Comment: @AndroidCoader : plz post your answer again  actually u have problem with line str="www:"+str first check it then repost. your answer is also right.thanks

Comment: @imrankhan i just forget to remove '{' in third line , thanks for guidance, If anything missing now then pls drop light on it :) . Edited now

Comment: @AndroidCoader : str="www."+str; line if url is str="http:.//myweb.com"; then i think according to your code str="www.http:.//myweb.com";

Comment: @imrankhan But the second requirement in quiestion mentioning the same `myweb.com = www.myweb.com`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13250/discussion-between-android-coader-and-imran-khan)

Comment: And what if the URL happens to contain `www` elsewhere, like "http://thisisawwweirdname"? Searching for `www.` is better, but you could still (unlikely but possible) have `http://oddwww.evenweirder". This situation really calls for a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not great with regular expressions, but I *believe* `^(http://)?+((.{0,2}[^w])|(.{3}[^.]))` accomplishes what you want:

```
String s1 = "www.myweb.com";
String s2 = "myweb.com";
String s3 = "http://myweb.com";
String s4 = "http://www.myweb.com";

String pattern = "^(http://)?+((.{0,2}[^w])|(.{3}[^.]))";
String www = "$1www.$2";

System.out.println(s1 + " -> " + s1.replaceFirst(pattern, www));
System.out.println(s2 + " -> " + s2.replaceFirst(pattern, www));
System.out.println(s3 + " -> " + s3.replaceFirst(pattern, www));
System.out.println(s4 + " -> " + s4.replaceFirst(pattern, www));
```

produces this output:

```
www.myweb.com -> www.myweb.com
myweb.com -> www.myweb.com
http://myweb.com -> http://www.myweb.com
http://www.myweb.com -> http://www.myweb.com
```

Since I don't consider myself strong with regular expressions, I'm not going to say this is foolproof, but it works on your example strings and on some tougher ones I tested it with.